# Jquery unreadable txt file

Tags: jquery

I am very very new to jQuery...beginner level at most. I have been trying to get my code to take in a .xml file but it says it cannot be loaded. I am running on my local host at the moment , my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

```
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div> <!--/header --> 

    <div data-role= "content">
        <ul id="myList">
        </ul>
                  <script type="text/javascript">

    console.log("starting.....");

    var xml;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"file:///C:/xammp/htdocs/MWA/lolcatz.xml",
            dataType:"xml",
            success:xmlParser
        });
        });            

        function xmlParser(data) {
            xml = data;
            $(xml).find("kitteh").each(function() {
                kitteh= $(this);
                var name=$(kitteh).find("name").text();
                var src=$(kitteh).find("url").text(); 
                $("#myList").append('<li>'+ name+ '<li>');
            });
    }
    </script> 
    </div><!-- /content -->
  <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>My Footer</h4>
    </div>  <!-- /footer -->
 </div> 
<!--    /page -->
 </body>
</html>
```

my lolcatz.xml is very basic

```
  <LolCatz>
  <kitteh>
  <id>1</id>
   <name>Ceiling Cat</name>
  <url>http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/90/Ceiling_cat_no_text.gif
   </url>
  </kitteh>
  <kitteh>
  <id>2</id>
  <name>Basement Cat</name>
    <url>
  http://i191.photobucket.com/albums/z37/beamerpi/TeeSting_s_Stuff/basement-cat-eats-souls.jpg
  </url>
   </kitteh>
 </LolCatz>
```

I dont know why this isnt working, can some one tell me why it doesnt work? or point me in a direction of another article here .
Many thanks.

Comment: You're not allowed to use files from disk. Instantiate vhost and put them into it.

Answer (score 0):

The file URL should be

```
 http://localhost/MWA/lolcatz.xml
```

you should check your XAMP config to know where your document root is!

Comment: this root is correct but the error in my console tool says....
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/MWA/lolcatz.xml. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Comment: you should also open your page through the server...in your browser "http://localhost/MWA/yourpage.html". If you open it as a file (you should see file:// in the browser) you will always get that error unless you disable browser security

Comment: In this case you'd better delete this question as it can't be useful to anyone.